# Having problems doing full screen in java

Tags: java, jframe

I am trying to make my window full-screen when a window is pressed (like the screen of a youtube video/movie). However, it won't happen, and I can still see my taskbar and the top bar which shows the maximize, minimize, etc. buttons.

I've tried it through this:

```
JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

and this:

```
JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice device = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
frame.setSize(device.getDisplayMode().getWidth(),device.getDisplayMode().getHeight());
```

However, the result I got was:
[image: second code img]

(I can see the left and right of the window)
Btw I have my taskbar on the left of the window, but putting it down does not change anything.

Comment: Perhaps look into using JNA to hide the task bar.